# Difficulty in using Dunn Test in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, scipy.stats, statistical-test

I am trying to use the Friedman test to identify statistically significant proteins. For the sample data set, the values are medians (as multiple trials were conducted but have been summarized already). There are two separate media and a control for each medium. Data has been collected for the amount of protein in each medium over a given time period. My goal is to compare the proteins in the two media and identify which proteins are present in statistically different amounts between the two media.

To accomplish this, I am trying out the Friedman test and then using the post hoc Dunn test. I have the following code but I am having trouble on getting it to work. I was wondering if anyone can offer any help or insights into why my code is not working? If you have any other suggested tests etc. to use for my purpose, that would be welcome as well.

```py
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from scipy.stats import friedmanchisquare
from scikit_posthocs import posthoc_dunn

# Sample data
data = {
    'Protein': ['Protein1', 'Protein2', 'Protein3', 'Protein4', 'Protein5'],
    'Control_Medium1': [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3],
    'Control_Medium2': [1.1, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.0],
    'Medium1_T1': [1.5, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0, 1.6],
    'Medium1_T2': [1.2, 1.3, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1],
    'Medium1_T3': [1.1, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.7],
    'Medium2_T1': [0.1, 1.2, 1.7, 1.8, 1.5],
    'Medium2_T2': [0.2, 1.4, 1.8, 1.7, 1.9],
    'Medium2_T3': [0.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.7, 1.4],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Perform Friedman test
control_medium1 = df['Control_Medium1']
control_medium2 = df['Control_Medium2']
medium1_t1 = df['Medium1_T1']
medium1_t2 = df['Medium1_T2']
medium1_t3 = df['Medium1_T3']
medium2_t1 = df['Medium2_T1']
medium2_t2 = df['Medium2_T2']
medium2_t3 = df['Medium2_T3']

_, p_value = friedmanchisquare(control_medium1, control_medium2, medium1_t1, medium1_t2, medium1_t3,
                               medium2_t1, medium2_t2, medium2_t3)

# Print Friedman test result
print('Friedman Test:')
print('p-value:', p_value)

# Perform pairwise comparisons with posthoc test
data_for_posthoc = [medium1_t1, medium1_t2, medium1_t3, medium2_t1, medium2_t2, medium2_t3]
labels_for_posthoc = ['Medium1_T1', 'Medium1_T2', 'Medium1_T3', 'Medium2_T1', 'Medium2_T2', 'Medium2_T3']

posthoc_result = sp.posthoc_dunn(data_for_posthoc)

# Apply Bonferroni correction to p-values
alpha = 0.05
corrected_p_values = np.multiply(posthoc_result, len(posthoc_result.columns))

# Get the significantly different proteins
significant_proteins = []

for protein in df.columns[1:]:
    if any(corrected_p_values[protein] < alpha):
        significant_proteins.append(protein)

print('Significant Proteins:', significant_proteins)
```

I have tried looking online for more information on the code for these statistical tests but I have not been able to find why my code is not working.

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: The error is: KeyError: 'Control_Medium1'
I have tried everything to get rid of this error but then new errors pop up

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is repeated and significant confusion between lists, Numpy arrays and Pandas dataframes. For this application you should basically never leave dataframes.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scikit_posthocs import posthoc_dunn
from scipy.stats import friedmanchisquare


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Control_Medium1': [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3],
    'Control_Medium2': [1.1, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.0],
    'Medium1_T1': [1.5, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0, 1.6],
    'Medium1_T2': [1.2, 1.3, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1],
    'Medium1_T3': [1.1, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4, 1.7],
    'Medium2_T1': [0.1, 1.2, 1.7, 1.8, 1.5],
    'Medium2_T2': [0.2, 1.4, 1.8, 1.7, 1.9],
    'Medium2_T3': [0.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.7, 1.4],
}, index=pd.Index(name='Protein', data=['Protein1', 'Protein2', 'Protein3', 'Protein4', 'Protein5']))
df.columns.name = 'Medium'


_, p_value = friedmanchisquare(*(
    col for name, col in df.items()
))
print(f'Friedman Test: p-value = {p_value:.2e}')
print()

long_df = df.iloc[:, 2:].stack()
long_df.name = 'Concentration'
long_df = long_df.reset_index(level='Medium')

posthoc = posthoc_dunn(a=long_df, group_col='Medium', val_col='Concentration')  # , p_adjust='bonferroni')

# This is not equivalent to skikit's Bonferroni correction!
posthoc *= posthoc.shape[1]

# Discard upper symmetric half
posthoc.values[np.triu_indices_from(posthoc, 0)] = np.nan
posthoc.index.name = 'MediumA'
posthoc.columns.name = 'MediumB'
posthoc = posthoc.stack()  # discards NaN
posthoc.name = 'P-value'

alpha = 1.0  # adjusted for demonstration
significant = posthoc[posthoc < alpha]
print('Significant media:')
print(significant.to_string())
```

```
Friedman Test: p-value = 8.00e-03

Significant media:
MediumA     MediumB   
Medium2_T3  Medium1_T1    0.749669
```

For a finer point, your last iteration seems dubious. Your post-hoc analysis is not comparing protein pairs, it's comparing experimental group (medium) pairs:

[image: posthoc matrix]

That's why the current output shows medium names and not protein names.

Your corrective factor is *not* equivalent to Bonferroni, and you should use Skikit's built-in correction, but I have left this commented.

By your current metric there are no statistically significant records so I showed the output above with alpha=1.0.

It seems suspicious that you include your controls for the Friedman test but not the Dunn test; but I've left that as-is.